# Execution post after resize (not repeatedly as the window is being resized)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When the user resizes the dialog it's executing POST below dozens of times. Is there a way to prevent it from executing $.post until the user releases the mouse button.

```
dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog',
  resize: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).dialog("option",
      ui.size.height + " x " + ui.size.width);
    $.post("savelayout.php", {
      menuheight: ui.size.height,
      menuwidth: ui.size.width
    });
  }
```

Edit: Removed updated code from example since it doesn't function.

Comment: http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/firing-resize-event-only-once-when-resizing-is-finished/

Answer (score 0):

My solution here tries to check if another resize was attempted in 100ms. If not run the post code.

```
var act;
dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog',
  resize: function(event, ui) {
    clearTimeout(act);
    act = setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).dialog("option",
        ui.size.height + " x " + ui.size.width);
      $.post("savelayout.php", {
        menuheight: ui.size.height,
        menuwidth: ui.size.width
      });
    }, 100);
  };
```

Alternatively there is a jQuery plugin : https://github.com/nielse63/jquery.resizeend if you want such an approach.

Comment: So there's no way to use some sort of stop function? I rather not use a timer.

Comment: nope.. not that i'm aware off. check in say 100ms is my best bet.

Comment: @michelle there is a jquery plugin to do what u want

Comment: i posted a modified version of my code with what you suggested. the syntax checks out as valid, but now it's no longer saving via php\mysql. disregard faux foobar values (i omitted my php variables)

Comment: did u put a `console.log()` to check if it is working

Comment: I just posted precisely what I'm using now for code. For whatever reason with your timer based solution POST is not executing.

Comment: what i meant is did u put a console.log before the post to check if the timeout technique is working. so we can confirm post was attempted and failed.

Comment: @michelle cud u remove `var act` from inside resize to outer scope!

Comment: done. still exhibits the same behavior. reflected changes above